# Drools infinite loop in decision table

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, drools, rule-engine, rule

I'm new to Drools and decision tables.  I need to create a rule to test if a Person is Older/young using the person age for the rule. The rule works but in infinite loop.

This is the rule, is basic, person age > 18 then the person is older, or, person age less than 18, person is young. The following is the HTML from my Excel file:

```html
<style type="text/css">
 table.tableizer-table {
  font-size: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC; 
  font-family: Courier New, Courier, monospace;
 } 
 .tableizer-table td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
 }
 .tableizer-table th {
  background-color: #DED11F; 
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th></th><th>&nbsp;</th><th>RuleTable Person</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>CONDITION</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>ACTION</td><td>ACTION</td><td>ACTION</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>p:Persona</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>edad >= </td><td>edad <</td><td>System.out.println( "Age: " + p.getEdad());</td><td>p.setMayorEdad($param);update(p);</td><td>System.out.println( "Older:" +p.isMayorEdad());</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Person rules</td><td>Status</td><td>Status</td><td>print</td><td>Is older?</td><td>Print ?</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Older</td><td>18</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>X</td><td>true</td><td>X</td></tr>
 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Yougn</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>18</td><td>X</td><td>false</td><td>X</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

My Persona class is a simple POJO for test the decision table:

Person class (static, in main class):

```
  public static class Persona{


    String nombre;
    String apellidoPaterno;
    String apellidoMaterno;
    int edad;
    float salario;
    boolean mayorEdad = false;

    public Persona() {
        super();
    }

    public Persona(String nombre, String apellidoPaterno, String apellidoMaterno, int edad, float salario) {
        super();
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidoPaterno = apellidoPaterno;
        this.apellidoMaterno = apellidoMaterno;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.salario = salario;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidoPaterno() {
        return apellidoPaterno;
    }

    public void setApellidoPaterno(String apellidoPaterno) {
        this.apellidoPaterno = apellidoPaterno;
    }

    public String getApellidoMaterno() {
        return apellidoMaterno;
    }

    public void setApellidoMaterno(String apellidoMaterno) {
        this.apellidoMaterno = apellidoMaterno;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public float getSalario() {
        return salario;
    }

    public void setSalario(float salario) {
        this.salario = salario;
    }

    public boolean isMayorEdad() {
        return mayorEdad;
    }

    public void setMayorEdad(boolean mayorEdad) {
        this.mayorEdad = mayorEdad;
    }



}
```

My main method, I'm using drools 6.5 with JRE 1.7:

```
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // load up the knowledge base
        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
        KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-dtables");


        Persona p = new Persona();
        p.setNombre("Person");
        p.setEdad(18);
        p.setMayorEdad(true);



        kSession.insert(p);
        kSession.fireAllRules();
        kSession.dispose();


    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this is the output, in infinite loop.

```
Age: 4
Older:false
Age: 4
Older:false
Age: 4
Older:false
Age: 4
Older:false
Age: 4
```

Thanks for any tip, link, tutorial, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you use `update()` on a fact, evaluation starts again, and the rule fires again, because the constraints are still true.

You could make mayorEdad a Boolean and add the constraint `mayorEdad == null`.

Or you can avoid the `update` if you don't expect other rules to fire based on the value of mayorEdad.